# Google Sheets Script Wildcards

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I know i can use wildcards with formulas like ;

```
=COUNTIF(A:A ; "*text*")
```

I want to run my code if A1 contains "text".

A1 = "test text"

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution :

```
 if(test.indexOf("2,")>-1)
{
    my code goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

For Google Apps Script you can use regular expressions. Any statement surrounded by forward slashes is interpreted as a regex if you hardcode it in apps script:

`/.*text.*/`

Note that wildcards are used slightly differently in RegExps: You need to include a dot `.` before your asterisk `*`:

    `COUNTIF()`:      `*text*`

    regex:                  `/.*text.*/`

So a quick script would look like this:

```
function matchText(text){
    try {
        var pattern = /.*text.*/;
        var isMatch = text.match(pattern)[0];
        return isMatch
    } catch (e) {
    return e.toString();
  }
};
```

A generalized custom function:

```
function matchText(text,pattern){
    try {
        var isMatch = text.match(pattern)[0];
        return isMatch
    } catch (e) {
    return e.toString();
  }
};
```

You can also still do this with native formulas using regexextract or regexmatch, which is always my favorite. Remember to use the correct regex wildcards notation with these: dot before the asterisk: `.*`.  Or just use `text` by itself, which automatically would find any instance of it:

[image]

Comment: (Terminology nitpick: "any ***statement*** surrounded by a forward slash is interpreted as a regex if you are hardcoding it in apps script: `/*text*/`" ↦ I think you mean ***expression***.  (Expressions form parts of statements.))

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1, "*text*"), "your code here", "Code not run: A1 doesn't contain 'text'")
```

Is this what you had in mind – formula code?  Or do you want to use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)?

(There may be a more intuitively named function than COUNTIF() for this, but it does the trick.)

Comment: i want to use Google apps script.